# How To Improve Quality of audio for Live Audio Streaming applicatio in java

Tags: java, sockets, audio

I am building peer to peer live audio streaming java application for an ad-hoc network.There are followings sample codes for real time voice communication based on UDP socket.

\ Sender

```
        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];        
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, adFormat);
        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(adFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();
        byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stopaudioCapture = false;
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(9786);
        while (!stopaudioCapture) {
            int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
            if (cnt > 0) {
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(tempBuffer, tempBuffer.length,ip,port);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                byteOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
            }
        }
        byteOutputStream.close();
    }
```

\Receiver

```
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[10000];
           while (true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + receivePacket.getPort());

            byte audioData[] = receivePacket.getData();
            InputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
            InputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteInputStream, adFormat, audioData.length / adFormat.getFrameSize());
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, adFormat);
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            sourceLine.open(adFormat);
            sourceLine.start();
            int cnt;
        while ((cnt = InputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                sourceLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
            }
```

I have made the connections using UDP connection.The application works fine and it's real time but voice quality is not good.I have to improve voice quality.I want yo know what else can be done to improve voice quality?
I can't use TCP because I need real-time communication.I have heard about RTP protocol but I don't know how to implement it.Is there any API in java to implement RTP?

Comment: The data comes from a microphone or a file? You have checked the quality of audio before sending it ? Maybe it is low quality from the source . The end user has interruptions ? The quality of internet connection is good ?

Comment: Data comes from the microphone.I have checked it and sound is not clear and incomplete(data gets lost).Voice quality is also good and I am using ad-hoc network not internet.

Comment: Check the data before you send it .  As an experiment try also a buffer size of 1024 or 4000. 

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS , how buffer size affects the voice quality?